# Java - DefaultHttpClient and "Host" header [Apache HttpComponent]

Tags: java, header, httprequest, host, apache-httpcomponents

I'm submitting multiple HTTP Requests via a DefaultHttpClient. The problem is that the "Host" header is never set in the request. For example by executing the following GET request:

```
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("http://www.myapp.com");
org.apache.http.client.HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(request);
```

The generated request object doesn't set the mandatory "Host" header with the value:

```
Host: myapp.com
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My fault. Actually the `DefaultHttpClient` do adds the `Host` header, as required by the HTTP specification.

My problem was due to an other custom header I was adding before whose value ended with 
"`\r\n`". This has invalidated all the subsequent headers added automatically by `DefaultHttpClient`. 
I was doing something like:

```
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("http://www.myapp.com");
org.apache.http.client.HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
request.addHeader(new BasicHeader("X-Custom-Header", "Some Value\r\n");
HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(request);
```

that generated the following Header sequence in the HTTP request:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
X-Custom-Header: Some value

Host: www.example.com
```

The space between `X-Custom-Header` and `Host` invalidated the `Host` header.
Fixed with:

```
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("http://www.myapp.com");
org.apache.http.client.HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
request.addHeader(new BasicHeader("X-Custom-Header", "Some Value");
HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(request);
```

That generates:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
X-Custom-Header: Some value
Host: www.example.com
```

Comment: Good catch! In my case (on Android) I was Base64 encoding a header value with [`Base64.DEFAULT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#DEFAULT), which includes line terminators. As a result all key-value pairs coming after the custom header got messed up (couldn't even see them when running the request through a proxy). Switching to [`Base64.NO_WRAP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#NO_WRAP) solved my problem, as it omits all line terminators (that is, the output is one long line).

Answer (score 3):

Just set the host header on the request using [addHeader](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpMessage.html#addHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Great answer. I was able to set a custom value for `Host` and confirm that it worked by getting http://djce.org.uk/dumprequest. That page dumps back the headers it receives, and sure enough, the value of `Host` was what I set it to (not `djce.org.uk`, which is what it would be if the Host value had not been changed).